# Cloud execution module - Profile is not defined Salt Stack

Tags: devops, salt-stack, salt-cloud

I am trying to set up the cloud execution module, and every time I try to bring up a test instance with "salt-cloud -p ec2_east_nano_prod saltcloud_nano_test", I get an error:

```
    [DEBUG   ] Reading configuration from /etc/salt/cloud
[DEBUG   ] Reading configuration from /etc/salt/master
[DEBUG   ] Missing configuration file: /etc/salt/cloud.providers
[DEBUG   ] Including configuration from '/etc/salt/cloud.providers.d/abc.conf'
[DEBUG   ] Reading configuration from /etc/salt/cloud.providers.d/abc.conf
[INFO    ] There's at least one cloud driver under the '-east-2-public' cloud provider alias which does not have the required 'driver' setting. Removing it from the available providers listing.
[DEBUG   ] Missing configuration file: /etc/salt/cloud.profiles
[DEBUG   ] Including configuration from '/etc/salt/cloud.profiles.d/ec2_us_west-2.conf'
[DEBUG   ] Reading configuration from /etc/salt/cloud.profiles.d/ec2_us_west-2.conf
[DEBUG   ] Configuration file path: /etc/salt/cloud
[WARNING ] Insecure logging configuration detected! Sensitive data may be logged.
[INFO    ] salt-cloud starting
[DEBUG   ] Could not LazyLoad parallels.avail_sizes: 'parallels' __virtual__ returned False
[DEBUG   ] LazyLoaded parallels.avail_locations
[DEBUG   ] LazyLoaded proxmox.avail_sizes
[DEBUG   ] Could not LazyLoad saltify.destroy: 'saltify.destroy' is not available.
[DEBUG   ] Could not LazyLoad saltify.avail_sizes: 'saltify.avail_sizes' is not available.
[DEBUG   ] Could not LazyLoad saltify.avail_images: 'saltify.avail_images' is not available.
[DEBUG   ] Could not LazyLoad saltify.avail_locations: 'saltify.avail_locations' is not available.
[DEBUG   ] Could not LazyLoad rackspace.reboot: 'rackspace.reboot' is not available.
[DEBUG   ] LazyLoaded openstack.list_locations
[DEBUG   ] Could not LazyLoad rackspace.list_locations: 'rackspace.list_locations' is not available.
[ERROR   ] Profile ec2 is not defined
[DEBUG   ] LazyLoaded nested.output
Error:
    Profile ec2 is not defined
```

**Setup**

/etc/salt/cloud.profiles.d/ec2_us_west-2.conf

```
ec2:
  provider: ec2-us-east-2-public
  image: ami-41e7cb24
  size: t2.micro
  ssh_username: ubuntu
  tag: {'Environment': 'production'}
  sync_after_install: grains
  minion:
        master: 172.31.17.185
```

Here is the provider.d file:

```
ec2-us-east-2-public:
  minion:
    master: master
  id: '**********'
  key: '******+******'
  private_key: /etc/salt/***.pem
  keyname: ***
  ssh_interface: public_ips
  securitygroup: default
  location: us-west-2
  availability_zone: us-west-2a
  provider: ec2
  del_root_vol_on_destroy: True
  del_all_vols_on_destroy: True
  rename_on_destroy: True
```

**Versions Report**

Salt Version:

```
           Salt: 2017.7.4

Dependency Versions:
           cffi: Not Installed
       cherrypy: Not Installed
       dateutil: 2.4.2
      docker-py: Not Installed
          gitdb: 0.6.4
      gitpython: 1.0.1
          ioflo: Not Installed
         Jinja2: 2.8
        libgit2: Not Installed
        libnacl: Not Installed
       M2Crypto: Not Installed
           Mako: 1.0.3
   msgpack-pure: Not Installed
 msgpack-python: 0.4.6
   mysql-python: Not Installed
      pycparser: Not Installed
       pycrypto: 2.6.1
   pycryptodome: Not Installed
         pygit2: Not Installed
         Python: 2.7.12 (default, Dec  4 2017, 14:50:18)
   python-gnupg: Not Installed
         PyYAML: 3.11
          PyZMQ: 15.2.0
           RAET: Not Installed
          smmap: 0.9.0
        timelib: Not Installed
        Tornado: 4.2.1
            ZMQ: 4.1.4

System Versions:
           dist: Ubuntu 16.04 xenial
         locale: UTF-8
        machine: x86_64
        release: 4.4.0-1038-aws
         system: Linux
        version: Ubuntu 16.04 xenial
```

I am not sure if I need to define "provider: pillar['cloud'][etc]".

Comment: What about `salt-cloud --list-providers` and `salt-cloud  --list-profiles`. For further assistance read [this](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/develop/ref/cli/salt-cloud.html)

Comment: Error: There was an error listing profiles: There are no cloud profiles configured.
Error: There was an error listing providers: There are no cloud providers configured.

Comment: i have also upgrade my salt-cloud to salt-cloud 2017.7.4 (Nitrogen). Everything is worked fine on salt-cloud 2016.11.9 (Carbon).

Comment: @dahrens are you there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `provider.d` file, try using "driver" instead of "provider", similar to the [salt-cloud quick start](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/cloud/qs.html#salt-cloud-qs).

[This page notes that this field was changed some years ago.](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/cloud/aliyun.html#configuration)

> Changed in version 2015.8.0.
>
> The provider parameter in cloud provider definitions was renamed to
>   driver. This change was made to avoid confusion with the provider
>   parameter that is used in cloud profile definitions. Cloud provider
>   definitions now use driver to refer to the Salt cloud module that
>   provides the underlying functionality to connect to a cloud host,
>   while cloud profiles continue to use provider to refer to provider
>   configurations that you define.